# Get UID of object after adding to the repository

Tags: typo3, extbase

So i'm trying to set up my first extension with Typo3 and i'm struggling very much. I want to set up an extension which handles reclamations from customers.

After submitting the input values i'll store the new customer in the database and directly after this step i'll get it back from the database to see which uid he has, to store the uid from the customer in the reclamation.

So i wan't to override the current `$customer-variable` with

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->findByName($name);
```

The returned result is not really an object of customer even `var_dump` is saying it is an customer-object. I can't call the function

```
$customer->getUid()
```

to get the current uid of this new customer. But i need the uid of the customer in my reclamation-object - how do i do that?

Next problem: every query i ll do to the db like

```
->findAll(), findByIdentifier($identifier)
```

is **null**.

I don't know why. It seems that he can't find the storagePid, but i've set up my TypoScript correctly.

I can only get a query when i add

```
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
```

any ideas where the dog is buried in this case?

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: Please split "Next problem" to a separate question bc. it's unrelated.

Answer (score 10):

Your initial question is hard to answer without more details. What is the relation between a customer and reclamations? If a customer can have multiple reclamations, it would be good to have an 1:n relation between customer and reclamations. In that case, you can just do `$customer->addReclamation($reclamation)` and don't need to take care about user UIDs.

As for your repository call, the problem is that your call gets you a QueryResult containing all matching objects. If `name` is really a unique property, you can do

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->findOneByName($name);
```

This looks for all customers with name equals `$name` (which should be only one) and returns the first one, so you get back a `Customer` object.

But this is not really necessary, too: If you persist all changes after adding the customer, you can get its UID:

```
$this->customerRepository->add($customer);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
// Returns the customer uid
$customerUid = $customer->getUid();
```

The persistenceManager can be injected like this:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 * @inject
 */
protected $persistenceManager;
```